# Save a response from API call to use in a test so I don't have to continuously repeat requests to API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api

API requests take too long and are costing me money in my Rails integration tests and my application.

I would like to save API responses and then use that data for testing. Are there any good ways to make that happen?

Also, how can I make fewer api calls in production/development? What kind of caching can I use?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question correctly. Maybe you could describe in more detail what you are trying to achieve or what you have envisioned. With that in mind, have you looked at caching frameworks, like memcached, ecache, etc.

Comment: @Jwan622 there is a number of answers waiting for you to accept. Please consider to choose one or leave a comment for a responder why his/her answer doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your rails app is using an external api, like a google/fb/twitter api, this kind of stuff

Caching the views won't work, because it only caches the template, so it doesn't waste time rendering the view again, and it validates that the cache is warm by hashing the data, which the code will still hit the api to verify that the hashes still match

For you the best way is to use a class that does all the api calls, and cache them in rails cache and give that cache a timeout period, because you don't want your cache to be too stale, but in the same time you will sacrifice some accuracy for some money ( like only do a single call every 5, 15, 30 mins, which ever you pick )

Here's a sample of what I have in mind, but you should modify it to match your needs

```
module ApiWrapper
  class << self
    def some_method(some_key) # if keys are needed, like an id or something
      Rails.cache.fetch("some_method/#{some_key}", expires_in: 5.minutes) do
        # assuming ApiLibrary is the external library handler
        ApiLibrary.call_external_library(some_key)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Then in your code, call that wrapper, it will only contact the external api if the stored value in the cache is expired.

The call will be something like this

```
# assuming 5 is the id or value you want to fetch from the api
ApiWrapper.some_method(5)
```

You can read more about caching methods from the [rails guide for caching](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html)

---

**Update:**

I just thought of another way, for your testing (like rspec tests) you could stub the api calls, and this way you'll save the whole api call, unless you are testing the api it self, using to the same api library I wrote above, we can stub the `ApiLibrary` it self

```
allow(ApiLibrary).to receive(:some_method).and_return({ data: 'some fake data' })
```

PS: the hash key `data` is part of the return, it's the whole hash not just the string.

Answer (score 2):

There is a great gem for this called [VCR](https://github.com/vcr/vcr/blob/master/README.md). It allows you to make a single request and keep response  cached, so every time you run the test you will use this saved response.

Answer (score 0):

I would use http://redis.io/ in conjunction with something like jbuilder.  So as an example your view would look like:

```
json.cache! ["cache", "plans_index"] do
  json.array! @plans do |plan|
    json.partial! plan
  end
end
```

for this controller:

```
  def index
    @plans = Plan.all
  end
```

If you have something that is a show page you can cache it like this:

```
json.cache! ["cache", "plan_#{params["id"]}"] do
  json.extract! @plan, :short_description, :long_description, 
end
```